Querying a nested field in milvus
I want to filter by a json which has lists as values
milvus_client.query(filter="dict['key'] == ['abcd']", collection_name="sample_collection")

how do I make this query work, I get,
pymilvus.exceptions.MilvusException: <MilvusException: (code=0, message=cannot parse expression: dict['key'] == ['abcd'], error: line 1:28 extraneous input '[' expecting {'(', EXISTS, '+', '-', '~', NOT, BooleanConstant, IntegerConstant, FloatingConstant, Identifier, StringLiteral, JSONIdentifier})>

